# Restful API - JSON response with single or all error(s)

Tags: json, rest, error-handling

My current project, a restful API, validates a POST request to create a new user and multiple errors could occur (with HTTP status):

1. username not set (400 BadRequest)
2. username is taken (409 Conflict)
3. server can't establish db connection (500 Internal Server Error)
4. ...

Should I immediatly send back a JSON response like this

```json
{
    "status": 400,
    "Message": "No username is set"
}
```

if an error was detected or should is it better if I accumulate all errors like here:

```
{
    "status": <HTTP STATUS CODE>,
    "errors": [
        {"message": "Username is not set."},
        {"message": "Can't access the database."}
    ]
}
```

The last approach would not require multiple request to send a valid payload. But which status code should be used, if the username is not set (400 Bad Request) or the server can't access the database (500 Internal Server Error)?

Comment: Do you see yourself collecting exceptions?  Normally, I would imagine, an exception is dealt with and not a show-stopper or its halts the request.  i cant imagine collecting exceptions.

Comment: Maybe I should send back an error response with each error appearance. But why should an exception halt a request? If the payload is not valid I will  not add the user to the db.

Comment: How can you get more than one error in one request?

Comment: Lets say I get a request where the username is already taken and not alphanumerical.

Comment: It would fail on the first validation check... which I presume is the alphanumeric check.  It would not go to the DB to look it up.  So its one error.

Comment: You're right, because I would not check further errors.

Comment: Yeah I think multiple errors might be rare.  But in the future if you come across a project where you take multiple requests nested, within one request, then you will still respond with 200 OK if some fail, but it would be good to get an error for each request.  But thats still one error per one request.

Comment: I have come across the frequent need to return multiple errors in a single Api response. Mostly pertaining to mult-threaded tasks. A request executes multiple mult-threaded tasks and each could return an error. I want all these errors included in the Api response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you foresee the need for multiple errors in one request, then the second JSON (with the multiple errors) is preferred.  Another benefit of doing the multiple errors response is that as a user of your service, if i get back multiple errors, I can address them all at one shot, instead of addressing them one at a time as I get them.

Comment: That's the benefit of sending multiple errors at once, but you've different status codes in the second JSON.

But I will stick with the one-error-per-request approach.

Comment: Yeah I agree because you wont come across two errors.  Thats why I put "if you foresee the need for multiple errors in one request" in my answer.  If that criteria is not met then stay with the first.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, the best (most standard) way to respond is a JSON structure of this form:

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "400",
      "message": "main error message here",
      "target": "approx what the error came from",
      "details": [
         {
            "code": "23-098a",
            "message": "Disk drive has frozen up again.  It needs to be replaced",
            "target": "not sure what the target is"
         }
      ],
      "innererror": {
         "trace": [ ... ],
         "context": [ ... ]
      }
   }
}
```

The multiple errors you want to place would be individual elements in the "details" array.  Using this structure you would still need some overall summary of the error, however the details would contain as many individual error messages as you want.

This is the format proposed by the OASIS data standard [OASIS OData](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Toc403940655) and seems to be the most standard option out there, however there does not seem to be high adoption rates of any standard at this point.

This also conforms to the [JSON RPC 2.0 Spec](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) as it requires that the error be an object in a "error" member, and that you have a code and message.

You can find the complete open source library that implements this at:  [Mendocino JSON Utilities](https://github.com/agilepro/purple/blob/master/purpleLib/src/main/java/com/purplehillsbooks/json/JSONException.java).   This library supports the JSON Objects as well as the exceptions.

The details are discussed in my blog post on [Error Handling in JSON REST API](https://agiletribe.purplehillsbooks.com/2015/09/16/json-rest-api-exception-handling/)